# doxygen doesn't show dependencies between static and public functions

Tags: c#, doxygen

HI,
I am trying to document my C# code using doxygen. The problem is that the dependencies between static functions and public/private function are not being shown. Where as, those between public/private are being shown correctly. Can anyone help me in this matter?

Pasting the config here along with some example code:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = abc
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.0
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../CodeDocumentation
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = YES
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = ../../Report/mycode
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
USE_INLINE_TREES       = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = FreeSans.ttf
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

A small eg

A csharp project contains the files:
lib.csproj

### A.cs

```
public static Class A
{
    public static void memberA()
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

### B.cs

```
public Class B
{
    public void memberB()
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

I reference it in a difference csharp project: Code.csproj
it has a code file like below:

### abc.cs

```
public class abc
{
    public void myfunction()
    {
        A.memberA();

        B objB = new B();
        B.memberB();    
    }
}
```

The above code, doxygen generates dependency diagrams and references list accurately for Class B and memberB(). But, it does not generate the same for Class A and memberA(). Both of them are included in the documentation. The only problem is that class A and its member functions being static, its dependency graphs are not generated.

Is this code helpful? Please revert back if need more clarity.

Thanks,
Vamyip

Answer (score 3):

Did you set EXTRACT_STATIC to YES? If so, a small code example showing the problem would help.

Comment: yes, and added config along with sample code. please check it. Thanks